# javascript post to database

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to save data into a database using `POST` and `AJAX`. The script runs as a user script for Firefox. When I run the script no errors is shown and nothing appears in the database.

**PHP**

```
    $db_connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    //$db_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT );  
    //$db_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );  
    //$db_connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $insert_key = $db_connection->prepare("INSERT into userstats (key, match, expire) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $insert_key->bindParam(1, $_POST["user"]);
    $insert_key->bindParam(2, $_POST["score"]);
    $insert_key->bindParam(3, $_POST["location"]);
    $insert_key->bindParam(4, $_POST["pointtime"]);
    $insert_key->execute();

    $db_connection = null;

    echo "saved to database!";

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**javascript**

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "stats.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}

var params = "?user=james&score=5&location=homepage&pointtime=1350249055";
xhr.send(params);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KEY` and `MATCH` are [MySQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so your statement is not being properly prepared.  Enclose them in backticks to use it as a column name:

```
 $insert_key = $db_connection->prepare("INSERT into userstats (`key`, `match`, expire) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

As for why it didn't throw an exception, make sure you actually have PDO configured to  throw exceptions. If you don't, the `$insert_key` will be `FALSE` and you'll get `E_WARNING`s for the subsequent attempts to bind params and execute it.

I would recommend making sure `error_reporting()` is enabled and `display_errors` is on, so in case you aren't getting exceptions thrown and instead got a fatal error that caused your script to terminate, you would at least see the error output returned back to the AJAX caller in your `console.log()`

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: wow i can't believe i missed that. hours and testingand it comes to that haha. also do i have to use mysql_real_escape_string on the POST or does PDO handle this?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 No you don't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` since that is part of a different API entirely. The bound parameters handle that internally.  I just updated by the way, `MATCH` is _also_ reserved and must be quoted.

Comment: While you are at it, it's a good idea to ALWAYS quote column names and tables to prevent stumbling into the next reserved keyword issue.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski  adding the error reporting helped now i get "Notice: Undefined index: username" and the same for all POST variables

Comment: @Mr.1.0 I don't think you should have the `?` at the start of your params string...

Comment: I note also that you have the `Content-length` header set, but the length of `params` won't be known yet and that will probably error.  Set `params` earlier before sending the headers.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski no luck i even tried commenting out the length parameter

Comment: @Mr.1.0 Then you need to start debugging in Firebug or Chrome network console or something. I pasted your XHR JS code and it successfully posts... And `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski how are you testing it in php. when i add var_dump($_POST) and paste the full url with parameters each one shows null